# Is Azure Service TopicClient Thread Safe & Reusable?

Tags: multithreading, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are using Azure SDK to publish message to Service Bus.
In Web API call we're doing these tasks repeatedly for each incoming request

```
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(conStr);
factory.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 3);
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(conStr);

TopicClient topicClient = factory.CreateTopicClient(topicName);
```

> Can topicClient be converted into Singleton & reused across multiple threads?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can topicClient be converted into Singleton & reused across multiple
>   threads?

Yes, that's the recommended practice. From [`Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients)

> Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are
>   created through a MessagingFactory object, which also provides
>   internal management of connections. **You should not close messaging
>   factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a
>   message, and then re-create them when you send the next message.
>   Closing a messaging factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus
>   service, and a new connection is established when recreating the
>   factory. Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that you
>   can avoid by re-using the same factory and client objects for multiple
>   operations.** You can safely use the QueueClient object for sending
>   messages from concurrent asynchronous operations and multiple threads.