# What is the purpose to use TopicClient.CloseAsync() for Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

After sending message to Topic, why to use the `TopicClient.Close()` or `CloseAsync()` method? What purpose is it? What if it does not call the `Close()` method after sending message?

Comment: I think you should review your question and clarify what API you are actually asking about. Are you sure there is a method `Close` on `TopicClient`? Have you done any research using the usual resources out there? If so, tell us.

Answer (score 2):

When producing messages, you would typically retain a long lived `TopicClient` to send more than one message, since when operating in [AMQP or SBMP modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-dotnet), keeping the client open will retain long lived connections to the broker. AMQP / SBMP modes are typically recommended over HTTP for [performance reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements).

(In fact, you may even share the TopicClient instance amongst threads since it's [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595039/is-azure-service-topicclient-thread-safe-reusable))

> Why to use the TopicClient.Close() or CloseAsync() method

i.e. you would only use the [sync or async Close methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.cliententity.closeasync?view=azure-dotnet) only when your application had no further use for the TopicClient, for instance when your application is exiting - this would be a graceful way to disconnect from the topic.